# IDataErrorInfo binding with Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, binding

I've implemented an IDataErrorInfo in my View Model. The problem is to validate the index of a Dictionary:

```
public class ViewModel : IDataErrorInfo
    {
        private Dictionary<string, string> reportFile;

public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                string result = null;

                switch (columnName)
                {
```

How can I validate each of the Dictionary index?

Comment: what do you mean, by validate the index?

Comment: Basically, each index of the dictionary is binded with TextBox. And I'm validating if the TextBox as same value inserted, if not tells the user that field is mandatory

Comment: So where you binding your text wouldn't this just be ValidatesOnDataErrors=true? I tried this in the past and it would put a red border around if there was an error